# SAS data step I/O operations optimization

Tags: optimization, sas

mydata1 is a heavy SAS dataset (let's say 8GB)

When doing this:

```
data mydata2;
set mydata1;
new_column = column1 + column2;
run;
```

SAS will write a new 8GB with only one new column.
Is it efficient?

is there anyway that SAS only writes to the end of the file mydata1, so that it optimizes the number of I/O operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a SAS dataset is written, each logical row is written in consecutive blocks; so it wouldn't be possible to add a new variable in place without rewriting the entire dataset.

If you're just modifying rows or values, that is possible; see the [MODIFY statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0g9jfr4x5hgsfn17gtma5547lt1.htm) for more details.  This works similarly to the SQL `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `INSERT` commands (at once!).

In terms of options, you can use a `data step view` to replicate what you want without the I/O cost.

```
data mydata2/view=mydata2;
 set mydata1;
 new_column = column1 + column2;
run;
```

That won't write out `mydata2` to a separate dataset, but stores the instructions for how to create it; then when it's later used (and it can be used as if it were a dataset, except it cannot be modified by things like `sort`) it has the new column on it.  The downside is if you use it many times, each time you use it you have to perform that operation; for a complex operation that could be expensive (the above would not be).

Comment: interesting choices that SAS is making... so I guess it is not best suited for huge datasets if you make the process repeatible

Comment: It's made to make data access predictable, among other things.  It's not particularly different from how, say, SQL works; you have to `alter table` to add a column before you can append data to it, you can't just use `update` to add something.  In general, you should structure your data ahead of time to have the right columns if you're concerned with this sort of thing.